# Shiny server: application failed to start

Tags: r, shiny

I have installed the shiny server on another ubuntu ip and using it through putty on windows. But the application is failing to start as you can see on the right column (An error has occured in bold). What configuration should I make to start the application on the shiny server? Please help.

I have opened the whole path to the R file in linux and the permissions are granted to the R file. Still not working.

Moreover, when I try to open the shiny-server.config file in etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.config , it shows:

```
[2015-08-19 12:13:59.666] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.4.0.721 (Node.js v0.10.21)

[2015-08-19 12:13:59.669] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2015-08-19 12:13:59.750] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: The user 'hadoop' does not have permissions to run applications as one of the users in 'shiny'. Please restart shiny-server as one of the users in  'shiny'. (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf:2:1)
[2015-08-19 12:13:59.751] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `Error loading config: The user 'hadoop' does not have permissions to run applications as one of the users in 'shiny'. Please restart shiny-server as one of the users in  'shiny'. (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf:2:1)`
says that you are trying to start shiny-server as a user named `hadoop` and this is not possible because the only user who can start this shiny-server is `shiny` and this is written in the second line of `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` file. Try to edit beggining of this file from

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;
```

to

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as hadoop shiny;
```

Comment: That was absolutely brilliant! Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: Just a quick FYI for anyone running systemd: you will also need to change the user in the `.service` file, e.g. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/shiny-server.service`.

Comment: Thanks, but is important restar latter of edit this files: {sudo systemctl restart shiny-server.service}